# Backward compatibility of WP7 development on Windows 7 and Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

My apologies if this is a duplicate, but I've not been able to find an answer to this.

My laptop was just upgraded to Windows 8, but my desktop is running Windows 7. I have several Windows Phone 7 apps in various stages of development. When the laptop ran Windows 7 I was able to open WP7 solutions on either machine without problem.

I know the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK has compatibility issues with Windows 8, and that the Windows Phone 8 SDK also supports Windows Phone 7.5, but will I still be able to open solutions on both machines, or will Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 save a newer solution format that Visual Studio 2010 won't be able to open? Or can I install the 7.1.1 SDK update on Windows 8 and still develop in VS 2010? (I understand I also need to install Games for Windows Live first.)

Comment: Yes. Atleast that's how I am doing it

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone 8 SDK supports both WP8 & WP7.1[/5].

You can open the same solution files with both VS2010 & VS2012.

If, for some reason you cannot open the same solution file it's easy to make versions for each version of VS. (Just take a copy and upgrade one of them.) Unless you're changing the projects within each solution this shouldn't be an issue.